# change range value on mousedown javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a range element which works as my web videos track bar. Currently it works as if the mousedown and released back to up then it jumps to that position of the video but the problem is that if the mouse's down and before mouse is released to up if the video `currentTime` changed then the tracker goes back to it's position where it was and the vide doesn't jump to the new position as the user clicked.

My question is how to change video `currentTime` on mousedown. This is what so far I'm doing:

```
var seeksl = document.getElementById('vidskb_r');
seeksl.addEventListener("change",vidSeek,false);
function vidSeek(){
    var skto=vid.duration*(seeksl.value/100);
    vid.currentTime=skto;
}
```

Which works as if the range value has changed.

```
seeksl.addEventListener("mousedown",vidSeek,false);
AND in my html range tag
<input type="range" class="vidskb_r" value="0" step="1" min="0" max="100" onmousedown="vidSeek();">
```

But none helped.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to change video currenttime on mousedown.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `input` event it fires on every interaction

```
seeksl.addEventListener("input",vidSeek,false);
```